# one external JavaScript file combine with multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a project that needs to have a header in all pages, I decided to use php for that and I have an external one JavaScript file. My problem is when the changed content on the html page page JavaScript start running function on that page, but it should not. I am interested how using one JavaScript file on multiple html pages, but there is no conflict. There is a solution to get around this, but it's not good. Plus I have light and dark mode on html pages, so I do not think it's good to create more JavaScript files with the same code :) thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear about the problem. It seems that the JavaScript file is included in a common header that's used on multiple pages, so the JavaScript is executed on all of those pages. What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: Js file is in footer section footer is also same on all pages. I dont know how change content with load new html page and keep same js and css file. Js after load new content show errors in console try execute function from first page

Comment: It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i create php index page and with include make part on that page header content footer...header have all from first html tag to div class container ad footer have close div of container and all other stuff with js links...